# How to place dropdownbox upon navigation bar in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, cordova

I have added navigation Bar and need to placed dropdown box on it, but dropdownbox hides under navigation bar, This is my dropdown box code

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="button">
<div id="ddmenu">
<ul>                
    <li>SHARE
        <div>
            <div class="column">
                <a id="sendFacebook" onclick="share(3)" href="#">Email</a>
                <a id="sendMMS" onclick="share1(3)" href="#">MMS</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>      
  </ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

button Class

```
.wrapper {
text-align: center;
 }

.button {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 20px;
}
```

navigationBar class

```
.navigationBar {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 45px;
background-color: #333;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
line-height: 44px;
font-size: 14pt;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
 }
```

What i tried is, changed the position of .navigationBar to relative but this made to navigation bar to appear at the bottom.

Comment: Hmm...Any scenarios.?(fiddle or pencode)..?

Answer (score 0):

Most easy hack around would be to add the CSS value of z-index for button Class.

```
z-index: 100;
```